# Creating a Gaussian 2d array with mean = 1 at specificed location

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, statistics, computer-vision

As the title says I have the following
: a NXN square one hot encoded array, which has a 1 on only one cell, and 0 on all others. This 1 can be anywhere on the grid and not necessarily on the center.

I would like to use **tensorflow** now make the square a gaussian like 2d array where the cell with 1 is the mean with the value 1, and all the cells around it are values <1 in a gaussian fashion.
Although the below code does not achieve what I want ( the center can be anywhere and the center value =1 and should decrease around it) to achieve the "soft gaussian weighted label smoothening" I am trying to achieve it is the closest I could approximate and serves as an illustration:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,10), np.linspace(-1,1,10))
d = np.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
sigma, mu = 1.0, 1.0
g = np.exp(-( (d-mu)**2 / ( 2.0 * sigma**2 ) ) )
plt.imshow(g, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

which outputs [example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xk8j.png)

Any advice/help for my problem stated above would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `scipy` to generate the gaussian kernel. And `np.where` to get the coordinates of the value 1.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 7   # kernel size
k1d = signal.gaussian(N, std=1).reshape(N, 1)
kernel = np.outer(k1d, k1d)
plt.imshow(kernel)
plt.show()

A = np.zeros((16, 16))
A[5, 9] = 1    # random
plt.imshow(A)
plt.show()

row, col = np.where(A == 1)
A[row[0]-(N//2):row[0]+(N//2)+1, col[0]-(N//2):col[0]+(N//2)+1] = kernel
plt.imshow(A)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks @Kh4zit this looks promising: will try it out! Do you know how would one go around achieving the same using Tensorflow? since scipy doesnt exist there

Comment: See @Lescurel 's `get_gaussian` function. Or you can compute the gaussian kernel using the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the probability distribution function from [`tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag` from `tensorflow_probability`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MultivariateNormalDiag#prob) :

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf

def get_gaussian(mu, sigma):
    mvn = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mu, scale_diag=sigma)
    x,y = tf.cast(tf.linspace(-1,1,10),tf.float32), tf.cast(tf.linspace(-1,1,10), tf.float32)
    # meshgrid as a list of [x,y] coordinates
    coords = tf.reshape(tf.stack(tf.meshgrid(x,y),axis=-1),(-1,2))
    gauss = mvn.prob(coords)
    return tf.reshape(gauss, (10,10))
```

An example with the mean (0.4,-0.6) and the variance of (0.5,0.5):

```
>>> g = get_gaussian([0.4,-0.6], [0.5,0.5])
>>> plt.imshow(g, extent=[-1,1,-1,1])
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: 2D gaussian]

Comment: thanks: this looks really good! I assume I choose the position of the label= 1 by combining it with the code of @Kh4zit above

Comment: is there any way to specify the size: number of cells that the gaussian stretches to like the code of Kh4zit above?

Comment: You specify the position by setting mu to the desired location: it's the mean of the gaussian, so it's correspond to the peak. For stretching the gaussian, you nead to play with sigma, which controls how "flat" the gaussian is. To get the peak to 1, you would need to scale it up, as a it uses a pdf, so the sum of the whole square is 1. (Easily achievable with normalization).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to accomplish this is to convolve with a Gaussian kernel (i.e. apply Gaussian smoothing).

TensorFlow has a 2D Gaussian smoothing in the function [`tfa.gaussian_filter2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/gaussian_filter2d).

Because the smoothing preserves the total intensity, the pixel that was originally 1 will have a lower value after. You can either manually compute the necessary scaling to bring it back to 1 (which depends on sigma), or you can simply normalize the image to have its maximum at 1.

I think it would be implemented something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np

img = (your array)
sigma = 1.0

size = ceil(3*sigma)*2+1
img = tfa.image.gaussian_filter2d(img, size, sigma, 'CONSTANT', 0)

img /= np.amax(img)
```

Computing `size` as above cuts off the Gaussian at a reasonable distance from the origin.

Comment: @astroboy: I've added my guess as to how to implement it with TensorFlow. I don't even have TensorFlow installed, but the docs are clear enough.